# Matrix of regression coefficients

Tags: regression, self-study, optimization, least-squares

Right above this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Covariance_matrix_as_a_parameter_of_a_distribution) here it's mentioned that the matrix of regression coefficients, $(\sum_{XX})^{-1}\sum_{XY}$, corresponds to the coefficients of an OLS solution. But I can't really see it for myself.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+normal+equation+-normalization+-logistic.

Comment: I don't see how those questions are similar to mine. Mine is about the covariance-variance matrix of the dependent and independent variables relation to the OLS solution.

Comment: Those questions are *identical* to yours, unless you mean something unusual by "$\Sigma_{XX}$" and "$\Sigma_{XY}$".  Feel free to edit your post to clarify the question and distinguish it from the others.

Comment: By those I mean the covariance matrix of the X vector and the covariance matrix(vector asssuming Y is 1-dim) of the vector of X and Y. Looking through the posts I've found this that resembles mine: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/using-covariance-estimator-to-perform-linear-regression. but it does not have an answer as to why it(covariance estimator?) works as a estimator for OLS.

Comment: I added a third duplicate that might make the resemblance more apparent.

Comment: Somehow I did not see that one.. Thanks.